# CakePHP 3.x - Getting database fields depending on Locale settings

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, translation, locale, cakephp-3.0

I got to develop a multi language website. It has more that 4 languages at the same time used in database. It's always following scheme:
field_%lang%

> ex. id | title_en | title_de | description_en | description_de

As its quite simple I was thinking to write a function I could use in both controllers and views (global Entity?) in order to keep my code DRY.

```
//function
public function __($field, $language = null){

    if( $language === null ){

        list( $language ) = split('_', I18n::Locale());

    }

    $newField = $field . '_' . strtolower( $language );

    if( $this->has( $newField ) ){
        return $this->{ $newField };
    }else{
        throw new NotFoundException('Could not find "' . $newField . '" field');
    }

}

//usage
$result->__('title'); //returns title_en depending on Locale
$result->__('title', 'de'); //always returns title_de
```

The thing is that I have no idea where to implement it without braking conventions. I was thinking about Entities but as I understand there is no "global" Entity that works for all models?

All ideas and suggestions are welcome!

Mike

Comment: Why not putting this in some kind of superclass of all your entity? I don't see why it would break conventions.

Comment: Yea, but is there any superclass of all entities? Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\Cake\ORM\Entity` is the base class of all your entities, you are not going to modify a built-in CakePHP class but nothing prevent you from creating your own superclass.

Let's call it `AppEntity`, just create a `AppEntity.php` file under `src/Model/Entity` and put your code inside:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\I18n\I18n;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;

class AppEntity extends \Cake\ORM\Entity {

    public function __($field, $language = null){

        if( $language === null ){

            list( $language ) = split('_', I18n::Locale());

        }

        $newField = $field . '_' . strtolower( $language );

        if( $this->has( $newField ) ){
            return $this->{ $newField };
        }else{
            throw new NotFoundException('Could not find "' . $newField . '" field');
        }

    }

}
```

Then, when you create an entity class, instead of extending `\Cake\ORM\Entity` you extend `AppEntity`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity;

class User extends AppEntity {

} ;

?>
```